# Access marker info

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I would like to use Google Maps for ExpressionEngine to place multiple markers and regions within an entry, using the fieldtype.

When I code up the template I would like to be able to access things like the postcode that is stored within the {markers} tag. But it seems to be one of the {types} within {marker:address_components} and returns 2 different types (postal_code_prefix|postal_code) and (postal_code). I'm guessing that if the location doesn't have the 2nd part it only stores the 1st option and if there is it only stores the 2nd option.

But how can I request one or other depending on availability, so I can have a heading of Postcode: and it inserts either the postal_code_prefix or postal_code depending on what's available?

Template code:

```
{exp:gmap:init id="map" scrollwheel="false"  style="width:800px;height:600px"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="info" entry_id="523"}

{cf_gmaps id="map"}

{cf_gmaps parse="markers"}

    {markers}
        <h2>Title: {marker:title}</h2>
        <b>Content:</b> {marker:content}<br />
        <b>Lat:</b>{marker:latitude}, <b>Lon:</b> {marker:longitude}<br />
        <b>Formatted address:</b> {marker:formatted_address}<br />
        {marker:address_components}
            <b>Short name:</b> {short_name}<br />
            <b>Long name:</b> {long_name}<br />
            <b>Types:</b> {types}<br />
        {/marker:address_components}<br />
        <b>Index:</b> {marker:index}<br />
        <b>Count:</b> {marker:count}<br />
        <b>Entry id:</b> {marker:entry_id}<br />
        <b>Offset:</b> {marker:offset}<br />
    {/markers}

{/cf_gmaps}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Resulting webpage for 2 of the markers:

```
Title: Mast
Content: 4 Distillery Cottages Tomatin Inverness Highland IV13 7YT UK
Lat:57.3413023239, Lon: -4.00712145789
Formatted address: 4 Distillery Cottages, Tomatin, Inverness, Highland IV13 7YT, UK
Short name: 4
Long name: 4
Types: street_number
Short name: Distillery Cottages
Long name: Distillery Cottages
Types: route
Short name: Tomatin
Long name: Tomatin
Types: locality|political
Short name: Highld
Long name: Highland
Types: administrative_area_level_2|political
Short name: GB
Long name: United Kingdom
Types: country|political
Short name: IV13 7YT
Long name: IV13 7YT
Types: postal_code
Short name: Inverness
Long name: Inverness
Types: postal_town
Index: 1
Count: 2
Entry id: 523
Offset: 0

Title: A9
Content: A9 Inverness Highland IV13 UK
Lat:57.341901478, Lon: -3.99473190308
Formatted address: A9, Inverness, Highland IV13, UK
Short name: A9
Long name: A9
Types: route
Short name: Highld
Long name: Highland
Types: administrative_area_level_2|political
Short name: Scotland
Long name: Scotland
Types: administrative_area_level_1|political
Short name: GB
Long name: United Kingdom
Types: country|political
Short name: IV13
Long name: IV13
Types: postal_code_prefix|postal_code
Short name: Inverness
Long name: Inverness
Types: postal_town
Index: 2
Count: 3
Entry id: 523
Offset: 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have in your templates and any relevant return data to see what's being served up?

Comment: I've added the code to my question